# Work done by a varying angle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

I know that work done by a constant force is $W=\vec{F}\cdot \vec{x}$, and that work done by a variable force is $\int \vec{F} d\vec{x}$. However, how do you calculate work done by a varying angle?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean *torque*?  Torques & angles are analogous to forces and distances, in that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it is the same formula.

$$W=\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x} $$

Check that this is the same as

$$\int_C |\vec{F}|\cdot \cos(\alpha)\cdot dx $$

This integral is a **path integral**, that means that you're summing all the contributions along all the tiny portions of the path of your trajectory.

Both $F$ or the angle can vary along the path. Anythin inside the integral can.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between $\int Fdx$ and $\int \vec{F}.d\vec{x}$.Basically a difference of dot product which is capable of calculating work by a variable angle.